# destroy class inside other class

Tags: c#

in this code I'm trying to Listening to multi connection at the same time with Asynchronous

Please how to destroy _receivedata class at this end of this code

```
class x

{

Thread t1; 
        int flag = 0;
        string receivedPath = "yok";
        public delegate void MyDelegate();
        BinaryWriter writer;

 private void sent_file_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            t1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(StartListening));
            t1.Start();

        }


 public class StateObject
        {
            // Client socket.
            public Socket workSocket = null;
            public const int BufferSize = 1024;
            // Receive buffer.
            public byte[] buffer = new byte[BufferSize];
        }


   public void StartListening()
        {
            byte[] bytes = new Byte[1024];
            IPEndPoint ipEnd = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 8221);
            Socket listener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            try
            {
                listener.Bind(ipEnd);
                listener.Listen(100);
                if (listener.Connected)
                {
                    allDone.Close();
                }
                else
                {
                    while (true)
                    {
                        allDone.Reset();
                        listener.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptConn), listener);
                        allDone.WaitOne();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
        }

        public void AcceptConn(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            allDone.Set();
            Socket listener = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
            Socket handler = listener.EndAccept(ar);
            StateObject state = new StateObject();
            state.workSocket = handler;
            _receivedata rceve = new _receivedata();
            handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0, new AsyncCallback(rceve.ReceiveData), state);
            flag = 0;
        }



        public class _receivedata
        {

            public void ReceiveData(IAsyncResult ar)
            {
                some code

                //how to destroy this instance of class at the end of this void

            }
        }


   }
```

when i use this code it destroy all class ,class _receivedata and class x

```
 public class _receivedata : IDisposable
        {

            public void ReceiveData(IAsyncResult ar)
            {
                some code

               Dispose() ;  //it destroy all class ,class _receivedata and class x



            }




        ~_receivedata()
            {
                 Dispose(false);
            }
            private bool isDisposed = false;


            protected void Dispose(bool disposing)
            {
                if (disposing)
                {
                    // Code to dispose the managed resources of the class
                }
                // Code to dispose the un-managed resources of the class

                isDisposed = true;
                 this.Dispose(disposing);

            }

            public void Dispose()
            {
                Dispose(true);
                GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
            }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what exactly you are looking for, but C# does have [destructors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66x5fx1b.aspx). Despite the name, these act more like finalizers than *real* destructors (which, by the way don't exist in .NET).

Example:

```
public class _receivedata
{
  public void ReceiveData(IAsyncResult ar)
  {
  }

  public ~ReceiveData()
  {
     // Finalization logic
  }

}
```

Comment: The MSDN docs are very misleading on this point; the `~` methods aren't really destructors, they're finalizers.  The closest thing to an actual destructor is `IDisposable.Dispose`, but there's really no such thing as a true destructor (despite the incredibly bizarre naming convention on MSDN).  I doubt very much that a finalizer is what the OP is looking for; he probably doesn't understand memory or resource management in C#/.NET.

Comment: @Aaronaught - Fair point. Will make sure to include this in the answer.

Comment: FTR - wasn't really intended as a criticism of your answer (which does just follow the documentation after all) - mostly just a warning to potential passers-by.

Comment: @Aaronaught - It's something that is somewhere in the back of my mind and this helps cement it ;)

Comment: when i use this code to destroy the class it destroy all class  it is destroy class  _receivedata and class x

Comment: @Bahgat Mashaly - I don't understand what you mean. Finalizers work on instances. Can you post your code?

Comment: @Bahgat Mashaly - It can't destroy the `x` class. Did it simply finish executing and was finalized by the runtime?

Comment: it gave me an exception and stop the program " An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in "AsynchronousServer.exe"

Comment: @Bahgat Mashaly - I am not surprized. Your `Dispose(bool disposing)` method will keep calling itself recursively until the stack is blown. Why are you calling `this.Dispose(disposing)` at the end?

Comment: I thank you for your cooperation and your time .

There will be a very large number of these instance  of the Class, I think that this will take lots of memory
So I try to free up memory
Is not this true ؟
What is your opinion if you have felt better

Comment: @Bahgat Mashaly - The GC will deal with any unreferenced instances. Don't over optimize this.